# Как считать значение qlineEdita c ечейки QTablewidgeta

Tags: c++, qt

[image: ТАБЛИЦА]

[https://pastebin.com/NtFFsn9Q][2]
здесь я додаю QLineedit в QTablewidget

```
    if(i==2)// I CREATE LINEEDIT IN TABLEWIDGET HERE
    {
      QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget(this);
       QLineEdit *line = new QLineEdit();
       line->setCompleter(StringCompleter);

       QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
       pLayout->addWidget(line);
       pLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
       pLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
       pWidget->setLayout(pLayout);
       ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1, i, 
      pWidget);
    }

  ето мои попитки считать значение QlineEdita

 // QLineEdit*l = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(0,2));
    it should
 //   be a code for getting qlineedit value


//   ui->lineEdit->setText(l->text());

/*QString StringItem;  My trying to get value of qlineedit
    QTableWidgetItem *pToItem;
     pToItem  = ui->tableWidget->item(0,2);
    StringItem=pToItem->text();
    ui->lineEdit->setText(StringItem);*/
```